# Google Analytics doesn't count visitors from https website

Tags: google-analytics

We are using HTTPS on our website since October 2014. There are links to companies in region of our city. When visitor clicks on link leading to website of our customers (companies), Google Analytics doesn't count those visits in their statistics. This happens since we started using of HTTPS. Before on HTTP Google counts our access to customers websites correctly. We have our own statistics, so we know, how much clicks visitors did and we can compare that with Google. Now there is zero on Google :(. Any ideas? Thank you very much! It is really hard to say that Google have bug in counting.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics works on both secure (https) and nonsecure (http) pages. 
If your page has https implements you must put https in your analytics code.

If you don't use the last version of analytics code, you will have to include the "s" in your code.

```
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Use:
http**s**

```
<script src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> 

</script>
```

Comment: I am talking about counters on customers websites, witch are http and witch doesn't count https visits... So this is not anser for my question but thank you anyway! - But I have solution already (will post answer extra).

Answer (score 0):

My appologize to Google. I was looking for solution a little bit more concentrated and problem is, that when https goes to http, it doesn't send HTTP_REFERER header - in default. You can change it by using meta tag referrer like this:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="always" />
```

I have tested that, and it really works! So simple, just to know what to look for :o).